# Closed question is edited to ask a completely different question -- approved edit?

Tags: discussion

A new user asks a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389786/which-database-server-should-be-preferred-for-developing-mobile-application-with

This question is closed by the moderators (an agreed action indeed).

The user then comes back some months later and edits the question completely, to ask something else entirely.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21389786/revisions

How can this be approved by site reviewers?!
I have reverted this edit, but how can site reviewers allow this? It looks to me like a blind acceptance of an edit without reading, likely because the text looked "different enough" from the source?

Comment: It's an OP edit - it doesn't need to be approved. Nobody approved it but themselves.

Comment: Well, that's too bad. Thanks @michaelb958.

Comment: I was going to guess that the user is question banned, but that might not be the case,

Comment: Generally speaking, if the post doesn't have any answers, then I have less of problem with this kind of change, but as soon as it has an answer that is invalidated by the edit, then edits like that need rolled bacl